# Генерация текстовых файлов с помощью Razor Pages в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, необходимо генерировать текстовые файлы по шаблону. Шаблоны часто меняются. Пробовал dotliquid, но он не подходит по ряду причин. Собственно вопрос, существует ли возможность использовать движок Razor Pages в отрыве от ASP? Находил только генерацию email по шаблону, но там не добраться до сгенерированного текста, что бы его сохранить. Заранее благодарю.